# How do I display array without the index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array from firestore that I have to put to events of full calendar.

What I want is to display it like this

```
[
 {
   title: '',
   start:''
 }
]
```

Not this

```
[{…}]
0
:
{title: "namee", start: "2018-09-19"}
1
:
{title: "namee", start: "2018-09-19"}
2
:
{title: "STI Night", start: "2018-09-18"}
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Comment: You have provided no code to show how you are rendering the output, but it looks like the type of output provided by the `console.log` feature built into the developer tools of a number of browsers. So is your question "How can I edit the source code of my browser to change the way `console.log` works?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the third `space` parameter of `JSON.stringify` to pretty print your array. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Syntax) for `JSON.stringify`.

```js
const a = [
  {
    title: '',
    start: ''
  }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
```